# Product of a periodic function and a non-decreasing function

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive function on $\mathbb{R}$. $f(x)$ is a non-decreasing function while $g(x)$ is a periodic function.

Assume that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is also a periodic function. Prove that $f(x)$ is a constant function.

It is easy to know that if $f$ is a periodic and monotonous function then it's a constant function. But the quotient of two periodic functions is not necessarily a periodic function.

So anyone has any ideals?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, at least as stated! Using the axiom of choice, decompose the rational vector space $\mathbb R$ as a nontrivial direct sum $\mathbb R=V\oplus W$. And define:
$$f(v+w)=e^{v+w}\qquad g(v+w)=e^{-v}\qquad h(v+w)=e^w$$
Then $g$ has period $w$ for any $w\in W$. And $h$ has period $v$ for any $v\in V$.

Comment: If both functions are continuous and the periods of g and fg are equal then the result is true.